# Java syntax to Groovy syntax

Tags: java, groovy, syntax

I am not really sure how to translate this to groovy syntax.

Have checked this [differences with java](http://www.groovy-lang.org/differences.html) page already.

Thanks!

```
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
       new X509TrustManager() {
          public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
          }

          public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {  }

          public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {  }

       }
    };
```

[image]

Comment: added screenshot to clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
import java.security.cert.*
import javax.net.ssl.*

TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = [
    [ getAcceptedIssuers: { -> null },
      checkClientTrusted: { X509Certificate[] certs, String authType -> },
      checkServerTrusted: { X509Certificate[] certs, String authType -> } ] as X509TrustManager
]
```

Comment: The code sample in the question has classic Groovy-style syntax, but this one in the answer looks cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

in groovy `{}` is always a block/closure. You would have to use `[ new X509TrustManager() { ... } ]`. If there are problems casting this dash an `... as TrustManager[]` at the end.